# How to add an "or" to =filter in Google Sheets

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm pulling my hair out. I need to add a bunch of rows from one sheet to another based on a few email addresses, like 44 of them.  I have it working with one but how do I do an "or"?

Below is the code I'm using.

Thank you!

```
=filter(Sheet1!A:G,Sheet1!C:C="name@name.com")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the '+' (plus) operator in your formula to do this...

Example:

```
=Filter(Sheet1!A:G,(Sheet1!C:C="name@name.com")+(Sheet1!C:C="name2@name.com"))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add multiple conditions to a `FILTER` function, the proper way to add an:

- `OR` is to use the `+` sign;
- `AND` is to use the `*` sign

```
=FILTER(Sheet1!A:G, CONDITION1 + CONDITION2 + CONDITION3)
```

#### Reference

- [How to filter data based on OR condition](https://support.google.com/docs/forum/AAAABuH1jm08nStFrjgO5Q/).